# Следующий шаг в vk_api

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, telegram-bot

В телеграмм боте есть:

```
msg = 'Сообщение'
bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, a)
```

Как сделать такой же, но в vk_api?

Comment: Что делает данный метод и что есть а?

Comment: Хм.. А не reply ли?